# regular expression which should not allow exe file format upload

Tags: regex

i have this file upload control which uploads all kinds o f files. i have to restrict it in such a way that it should not allow exe formats..could anyone please help me with this..i cannot enter allowed file formats as it is unpredictable ..i need to restrict only exe format ..thanks in advance

Comment: You do know that executables can have lots of other endings? Just rename `foo.exe` to `foo.scr` for example. Instant screensaver, will execute just fine when double-clicked. And you can do a lot of damage with Windows scripting files etc., too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
^(?!.*\.exe$).*$
```

[Rubular Link](http://www.rubular.com/r/itkMUiGgh4)

Comment: Don't forget the case insensitive modifier!

Comment: the above expression works perfectly in firefox too..thanks a lot

Comment: could anyone tell me how to add case insensitive to the above expression without affecting it?..

Comment: Give your regex engine the 'i' modifier.

Answer (score 0):

This regex would match a string beginning with any characters ('^.*') and ending in ".exe" ('\.exe$'):

```
^(.*\.exe)$
```

Tested it here: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html